# How to have no default value in editbox bound to managed bean with datatype double?

Tags: xpages

I have an edit box that is bound directly to a value in a managed bean.   The value is set using one line of expression language.  The value in the bean is of type double, which by java default is set to 0.0.

The code is:
     statusBean.adMoney

In my xpage, I do NOT wish to show a default value.  I want the user to enter a value without having 0.00 as default, I just want to show an empty edit box.

Please share your best approach to accomplishing this.  Is it possible to bind directly to a bean in SSJS and still have it editable?  Is it possible to do an if statement in EL?   Am I just better off making the data type a String, and converting the value when I need to do math against it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this customConverter to your inputText field

```
<xp:inputText
    id="inputText1"
    value="#{statusBean.adMoney}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:customConverter
            getAsObject='#{javascript:value=="" ? 0 : parseFloat(value)}'
            getAsString='#{javascript:value==0 ? "" : value.toString()}' />
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

It hides always the value "0.0".  The field will be empty at the beginning and every time user puts in "0" and submits.

**Update:**

In case "0" is a valid value then this is a better solution:

Use in bean instead of a `double` field a `Double` field. As `Double` is a class it can be  `null`. Adapting code from above it would look like this:

```
<xp:inputText
    id="inputText1"
    value="#{statusBean.adMoney}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:customConverter
            getAsObject='#{javascript:value=="" ? null : parseFloat(value)}'
            getAsString='#{javascript:value==null ? "" : value.toString()}' />
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

But the good news are that this customConverter behaviour is already standard for inputText controls. Whenever the `Double` field value is `null` it is shown as empty value in editbox. When user deletes the number in editbox the field in bean is set to `null`.

That's why we need only this code if we use `Double` field instead of `double` field:

```
<xp:inputText
    id="inputText1"
    value="#{statusBean.adMoney}">
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: Knut, This does work, but zero is a valid entry.  My goal is to make the user think about it, and then enter zero if that is the what they want to enter.   Let me play with it and see if I can make this work.

Comment: In case "0" is an valid value you can use another "hide" value (e.g. -1 or -12121212). Set this value in your bean as default and use it in custom converter instead of "0"

Comment: Great suggestion, the value can't be negative.  Now I have the issue with the value converting to NaN when I validate the form.   The value is required, but it looks like I am going to have to write a custom validator.

Comment: I can avoid the NaN by writing a custom validator.  Thanks again for you help!

Comment: I thought I would give a quick update to wrap this up.  I had to pull out my 2 inch thick Javascript book to find this.  The built-in function isNaN() will be very helpful to include in a custom validator to check if the user actually entered a number.  If you don't use a custom validator with the technique that Knut gave above then the system will add the value 'NaN' when submitted.

Comment: I updated my answer. My recommendation is to use `Double` instead of `double` for field in bean. Validators e.g. `xp:validateDoubleRange` and `xp:validateRequired` are working fine for me. Which validator caused stress with NoN?

Comment: It wasn't the validators causing the NaN.  It happened when I went the next xpage and then back.  The validators fixed the issue.   I briefly considered using the wrapper, but didn't think it through.  Since it is an object, it can be null.  Good thinking!